# Select if it does not exist in another table, but if there is no record in 24h

Tags: mysql

**I have two tables:**

Links
[image]

Works
[image]

***I need to return the values from the links table, but first I need to see if it exists in the works table, and if it has to have been inserted more than 24h, otherwise that record can not be returned in the query.***

**Querying and returning only what I do not have in the works table is easy, I do so:**

```
SELECT *
FROM links l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM works w
    WHERE w.linkId = l.linkId
)
```

***But I need to return only records entered more than 24h***

Comment: Add a where clause using your date field

Comment: Why not use a left join and a where condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to exclude rows UNLESS they have been there for more than 24 hours. This should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM links l
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM works w
    WHERE w.linkId = l.linkId
    AND w.datahora > date_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)
)
```